# Посоветуйте литератеру и курсы по системному программированию под Linux (Москва вечер || онлайн)

Tags: linux, системное-программирование

Какую литературу по-русски стоит прочитать?

И насколько полезны курсы на сайте Специалист.ру? Есть ли альтернатива?

1. https://www.specialist.ru/course/yun1-b
2. https://www.specialist.ru/course/unsi
3. https://www.specialist.ru/course/unsis

Некоторая основа в программирование есть (основная моя работа ПЛИС, микроконтроллеры, GUI программы на C#). Цель научить работать со встраиваемыми системами под Linux - TI Sitara, SoC (Altera, Xilinx). Т.е. портирование, установка, написание программ преимущественно без графического интерфейса, написание драйверов для подключаемого к процессору железа (в том числе самописному на ПЛИС).